# Is there a natural source of Antimatter in this universe?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, universe, antimatter

I was just asking if there is an natural source of Antimatter in this universe capable of creating simple molecules/compounds? So, any good answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antimatter, although only in the form of positrons, is produced by many nuclides during the [β⁺ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission). I can not get any reliable source, but vast majority of such β⁺ nuclides seem to be artificially prepared in a reactor, so this is perhaps not a truly natural source.

Other article, named ["Antimatter from bananas"](http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/2009/07/23/antimatter-from-bananas) states otherwise. The concentration of radioactive potassium-40 can be however affected by our nuclear tests, since e.g. carbon-14 concentration has [grown several times after atmospheric explosions of 1950s-1960s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-14#/media/File:Radiocarbon_bomb_spike.svg). I found no data on K40.

Independently, some antimatter, still in the form of exotic particles, [seems to come from unknown (?) sources in the universe](http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/april-2015/ten-things-you-might-not-know-about-antimatter), or is created in form of [showers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_shower_%28physics%29) upon high-energy particles interacting with the atmosphere as observed by the [Pierre Auger Observatory](https://www.auger.org/).

Comment: Yeah, I heard of an observatory(can't remember what one though) spotting some Antimatter in a thundercloud, Has anyone discovered a place(at least theoretically) in the universe that produces enough Antimatter to make molecules/compounds?

Comment: You are right; in fact the "Antimatter from bananas" article also mentions antimatter would emerge from thunderstorms. Also, the Hawking radiation from black holes could generate a lot of antimatter when the black hole is small. But I can not imagine any process in the universe generating exclusively antimatter, deaccelerating it and confining it long enough to form molecules.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways to make antimatter "naturally".  One of the most common is [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production).  A high energy photon is converted into a particle / anti-particle pair.  For example, a photon with energy greater than about 1 MeV ($E > 2 \, m_\mathrm{electron}c^2$) can turn into an electron positron pair (some more considerations are needed to conserve momentum in addition to energy...):

$$\gamma \rightarrow e^- + e^+$$

There are many, many other examples of pair production, my favorite is:

$$ p+p \rightarrow p+p+p+\bar{p} $$
where two high energy protons collide and produce an additional proton anti-proton pair.  In this case you need enough kinetic energy in the initial particles to match the mass energy of the new proton and anti-proton.

Pair production always gives both matter and anti-matter, so it can't account for the fact that we observe mostly matter in the universe.  This is an open problem in particle physics: to determine why the universe doesn't contain an equal amount of matter and anti-matter.

You can also make anti-matter through other processes.  Nuclear beta decay, where a neutron decays into a proton and electron, also produces an anti-neutrino.  This is how radioactive carbon-14 decays to stable nitrogen-14.

$$ n \rightarrow p + e + \bar\nu_e $$

That's an anti-electron neutrino needed to conserve lepton number.

The moral of the story is that there are lots of naturally occurring processes that produce antimatter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I meant to ask if is there any known source in the universe the will produce suffcient amounts of Antimatter for the creation of simple molecules/compounds Anything?